# How to assign some value to input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I need to put some value to  element.

Here is my code snippet.

```
var userId = localStorage.getItem('keyName');

  var Name = document.getElementById('Name');

  var dbRefName = firebase.database().ref().child('Web App').child('Users').child(userId).child('Name');


     dbRefName.on('value', snap => Name.innerText = snap.val());
```

I am trying to assign this `Name` value using `id` to the input element shown as below.

```
<input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Username" >
```

It can assign using `id` to `<span>` elements. But it is not working with `<input>` elements.

Could anyone please help me on this matter?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.value` instead of `.innerText` for `<input>` elements, like so:

```js
document.getElementById('input').value = 'foo'
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
```

Comment: Dud, Without `.innerText`, the firebase query not working.

Comment: The firebase query and how you assign value to an element are irrelevant to each other. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: But this method is working with '<span>' element. Here is the result when I use `id` attribute with a span element.  `<span id="Name">John Smith</span>`

Comment: @AdminLetsgo the elements like `input` and `img` have no inner context, so they have no such props as `innerText` and `innerHTML`. The value that is displaying inside the `input` is being stored in `input.value` property. Nik Kyriakides is right, provided changes does not refferencing to firebase **at all**, so, seems like, your problem with firebase query belongs to something else.

Answer (score -1):

Input HTML elements needs **name** tag, and the way to assign it a value is by the **value** tag or by `.value` in Javascript

```js
var input = document.getElementById('name');

//input.value = localStorage.getItem('keyName');

input.value = 5;
```

```html
<input type="number" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name here" value="1">
```

Comment: `input` elements do not *need* a name attribute.

Comment: Technically they are not required, but if you send form normally you have to use them to retrieve your datas in the back ... If you don't specify name tag the input would not be submitted! Oh and last thing but not least, with name tag in your input you can get it easily with javascript like this : `document.getElementById("form").elements.*name*;` so yes it's not obligated, but it should be!